# How can I put listbox text/items into a text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I want to make some sort of management system or list maker. And I want the data to be stored in a text file. Here's what I have.
So when you click then exit button on the form

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists("paste.txt"))
    {

    } 
    else if (File.Exists("paste.txt"))
    {
        File.Delete("paste.txt");
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("paste.txt");
        string text = listBox1.Text;
        file.Write(text);
        file.Close();
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

So I want it to save all the text in the textbox to a text file. How could I do this? Right now when I click the exit button the file stays blank.

Comment: wpf? winforms? uwp? xamarin?

Comment: Sorry, for the
```
 if (!File,Exists("paste.txt)) 
{
StreamWriter file =  new StreamWriter("paste.txt")
File.Write(listbox1.Text)
File.close();
```
}

Comment: i would like to know in win forms

Comment: You don't need the if statement, File.Delete will not throw an exception if the file doesn't exist. I also think you want the listbox items, not the text.

Comment: I might sound silly, but may be you have multiple versions of paste.txt in the current working directory. goto windows explorer and make sure you have only one copy of paste.txt. if you have multiple versions, then take the one with latest modified date (from your bin\debug directory may be).

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("someTextFile.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBox1.Items.OfType<object>().Select(item => item.ToString())));`. Use full paths (you cannot be sure where the file will end up if you don't). If the file exists, it's overwritten. Otherwise, it's created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.WriteAllText`. This will overwrite what's in it at all times, so there's no point in deleting it first if that's what you want.

```
var path = "paste.txt";
var listBoxText = "";

foreach(var item in listBox1.Items) 
{
    listBoxText += item.ToString() + "\n"; 
}

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, listBoxText, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Not sure what your requirements are OP, but if you also want to create the File if doesn't exist, you could do:

```
var file = new FileInfo(path);
file.Directory.Create(); // will do nothing if it already exists
File.WriteAllText(path, listBox1.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: File.WriteAllText creates the file if it doesn't exist, overwrites it if it does, so the creation lines above it are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pretty way of doing it

Lets say you have an item object

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayValue 
    { 
        get
        {
             return $"[{Value}] - {Description}";
        }
    }
}
```

You see, I provided an object that could be like that, more complex object, but could be just a string.

When you add objects you create a list and do something like this

```
var itemList = new List<ListItem>();
// add items
myLst.DisplayMember = "DisplayValue";
myLst.ValueMember = "Value";
myLst.DataSourse = itemList;
```

In this case you can get the list of "any property" like this (System.Linq)

```
string[] fileLines = 
    ((List<ListItem>)myLst.DataSourse).Select(itm => itm.Value).ToArray();
```

Or, if your items are simple strings

```
string[] fileLines = (from itm in myLst.Items select itm).ToArray();
```

And then use your file logic to simply in the end call

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, fileLines);
```

What I like about this approach is that no explicit loops needs and item can be a more complex item that can have a bunch of properties beyond a simple string description/value in one.

Comment: Thanks guys! It works now. Thanks for all your guys help!

Comment: @leonlejunchen In this case, please up-vote questions you found helpful and accept one that fits your needs/explains better. Thanks

Comment: Alright thanks. Sorry, Im kinda new to this whole programming community.

Comment: @leonlejunchen get old